# Generate a SELECT dropdown upon selecting another SELECT

Tags: angular

I have a form where upon selecting a SELECT dropdown another SELECT dropdown list is being generated. In both of the SELECTs the OPTIONs are being generated by `ngFor` since data is coming from database through service. I have used `click`, `select` and `change` functions in the first dropdown to generate the second dropdown choices but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.select1Service.getSelect1().subscribe((options1) => {
      this.options1 = options1;
  });
}

  populateSelect2(id: number) {
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.select2Service.getSelect2(id).subscribe((options2) => {
      this.options2= options2;
      console.log(this.options2);
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="input1" class="col-form-label">Select 1
                <span class="red-text text-accent-4">*</span>
              </label>
              <select id="inputArea" class="form-control" formControlname="in4">
                <option selected>Choose option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of options1" value="{{item.id}}" (change)="populateSelect2(item.id)">{{item.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
              <p>Select 2
                <span class="red-text text-accent-4">*</span>
              </p>
                  <select id="input2" class="form-control" formControlname="in6">
                    <option *ngFor="let item of options2" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
                  </select>                
            </div>
```

Comment: the (change) must belong to the **< select>** tag, NOT to the < option> tag

Comment: what is the issue ? are you able to generate the second drop down ?

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code like how are you handling the `change` event of the first dropdown. 
1. First of all the `change` should be used on the select tag and not on the option itself like below

```
<select id="inputArea" class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "selectedFirst" formControlname="in4" (change)="populateSelect2($event.target.value)">
                <option selected value="">Choose option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of options1" value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</option>
              </select>
```

2. I prefer to use  `[(ngModel)]` to store the selected value of the dropdown instead of directly passing `item.id` to the function itself. you can use `$event.target.value` to get the current value of the dropdown1 after changing it's value like below -

`(change)="populateSelect2($event.target.value)"`

Here is the full working code for your component -

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {SelectfirstService} from './select1service';
import {SelectSecondService} from './select2service';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
selectedFirst : string = "";
 options1:any[];
 options2 : any[];
  constructor(private select1Service:SelectfirstService,private select2Service:SelectSecondService){

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.select1Service.getSelect1().subscribe((options1) => {
      this.options1 = options1;
  });
}

  populateSelect2(id: number) {
    console.log('selected value from first dropdown:',this.selectedFirst);
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.select2Service.getSelect2(id).subscribe((options2) => {
      this.options2= options2;
      console.log(this.options2);
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML template `app.component.html`

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
              <label for="input1" class="col-form-label">Select 1
                <span class="red-text text-accent-4">*</span>
              </label>
              <select id="inputArea" class="form-control" [(ngModel)] = "selectedFirst" formControlname="in4" (change)="populateSelect2($event.target.value)">
                <option selected value="">Choose option</option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of options1" value="{{item.id}}" >{{item.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
              <p>Select 2
                <span class="red-text text-accent-4">*</span>
              </p>
                  <select id="input2" class="form-control" formControlname="in6">
                    <option *ngFor="let item of options2" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</option>
                  </select>                
            </div>
```

I have created two sample service class below for testing

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SelectSecondService {
  run() {
    console.log('app service');
  }

getSelect2(id:number):Observable<any[]>{
   let secondOptions :any[] = [];
   secondOptions.push({id:1,name:'option1'});
   secondOptions.push({id:1,name:'option2'});
   secondOptions.push({id:1,name:'option3'});
   secondOptions.push({id:2,name:'option1'});
   secondOptions.push({id:2,name:'option2'});
   secondOptions.push({id:3,name:'option1'});
   secondOptions.push({id:3,name:'option2'});

   return Observable.of(secondOptions.filter( x => x.id == id));
  }


}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SelectfirstService {
  run() {
    console.log('app service');
  }

  getSelect1():Observable<any[]>{
   let firstOptions :any[] = [];
   firstOptions.push({id:1,name:'option1'});
   firstOptions.push({id:2,name:'option2'});
   firstOptions.push({id:3,name:'option3'});
   return Observable.of(firstOptions);
  }

}
```

Here is a working demo link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwxunh

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That worked like a charm. I'm using Reactive forms so didn't used `ngModel`. Nevertheless thanks again for your detailed solution